# While getting parameters shows as empty from AWS Parameter store using ssm

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-ssm

I already configured AWS credential in my machine. But I couldn't read AWS Parameter store values. It shows empty

```
:~ aws ssm describe-parameters

{
    "Parameters": []
}
```

**Note**: Parameters are created by the person having the role of "AdminRole" in AWS account.

Referred from the doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html)

Comment: SSM Parameter Store -- like most AWS services -- is regional.  You need to be using the same region, here, that you are using in the console.  Check this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes I have checked with the region it's changed from AWS config in my local machine. Now It resolved Thanks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot do you know what is the maximum expiration time for CloudFront signed url? It can be a permenant url?

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question since it was essentially just a simple misconfiguration.  As for the CloudFront question, I believe the maximum is currently January 2038 (when the Unix epoch reaches 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647) but you should post that as a separate question and I'll find an authoritative answer.